# Ubuntu lamp-server vs separate installations?

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, lamp

**Is there a difference in using lamp-server vs installing Apache, MySQL, and PHP separately by themselves?**

I am transferring a website from Windows to Linux. It is a dynamic MySQL + PHP website running on a local network. The website is accessible by other computers both on WiFi and Ethernet that are on the same network.

I have used WampServer before for localhost-only training purposes as well as the Apache, MySQL, and PHP by themselves for the public website. The server is going to use Python for some CGI scripts as well.

I know that WampServer is mostly used for training and not for hosting open websites, so I wonder if it is similar in LAMP stack.

The computer is going to have Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 installed on different partitions of the same machine.

Finally, could someone please provide a good guide on the difference in configurations between Ubuntu and Windows versions of Apache? (Where are the config, htdocs, and log files; how to monitor and manage MySQL and Apache?)

Answer (score 2):

Installing LAMP is essentially the same as installing each component separately. It's especially the better route for a beginner, since you're ensured that everything is installed properly.
There are a lot of things you'll need to research and study for this. First, simply learning the Ubuntu commands. But, I definitely recommend an Ubuntu LAMP server over a Windows one.
It would be hard for anyone to just tell you everything you need to do though, in a forum post. You'll need to get your information from multiple tutorials. Configuration file for php is in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and your apache configuration file will typically be /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. If you want to use /var/www instead of /var/www/public_html as the website root directory you'll need to change that in apache2.conf, since in ubuntu 14.04 the default is public_html

```
<Directory /var/www/> //instead of /var/www/public_html/
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Just find that line and change it.
Also remember to run the command:
    service apache2 restart
After every configuration change so they will take place in the server.
These are just random tips for the process, for most of it you'll need tutorials. But, first learn your Ubuntu commands.

Comment: I know the Ubuntu command line basics pretty well, and I have been trying to install LAMP in a virtual machine. There is one problem so far, how can I change permissions to the www/html/ folder so I can edit it? Also, the main question, is there a difference in `sudo apt-ge install lamp-server` vs `sudo apt-get install apache2` then `sudo apt-get install etc.?

Comment: I'm assuming apache2 just wouldn't have the other components that LAMP does. And to change permission of files you use the chmod command. But you need to login to run your file editor as sudo to edit the files. You want to keep owner of files in www as www-data and keep the permissions at 775. To change permissions:
sudo chmod 775 vita /path/to/folder -R
To check the owner of the files run
ls -l
And if they aren't www-data
Run sudo chown www-data:www-data /path/to/www -R

Comment: I regularly find myself logging in as a specific user, e.g. ubuntu@, and find it valuable to identify that user when setting ownership.  Thus, if you can make that same assertion, I frequently like to set ownership to ubuntu:www-data rather than www-data:www-data.

Comment: Oh Yeah I actually set mine to ftp-user:www-data actually. Then just log into root (sudo -i) if I need to make changes via the terminal.